# PHP move_uploaded_file() not working (failed to open stream)

Tags: php, upload

I'm making a tiny thing for me to upload files to my web server from a screenshot application (ShareX if it matters, so security is not much of a concern, but it's still on my mind) and I'm having trouble getting the uploaded file to work. The system generates a unique 5 character alphanumeric string to hold the image under (a la `i.imgur.com/aaaaa`) and stores that in a SQL database for retrieval when a user looks at it. The system also works as a link shortener, of which the link is stored in that row's `value` column.

The uploaded image is *supposed to* be stored under that 5 character random name with the extension of the original uploaded file. The name of the moved file is put under the `value` column for retrieval later.

Uploading a file with a test HTML form puts the following in the apache error log:

```
PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file({webroot}/i/uploads/mS1H6.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in {webroot}/i/index.php on line 48
PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpKAoPjZ' to '{webroot}/i/uploads/mS1H6.png' in {webroot}/i/index.php on line 48
```

The code for the uploader file is as follows (all incoming requests to the folder are `.htaccess`ed to this file):

```
require("./uploader_settings.inc.php");

$conn = mysqli_connect($db_url,$db_user,$db_pass,$db_database);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    http_response_code(500); //server error
    die();
}
//handle content
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    {sanity checks}

    //actually do it
    $value =  $_POST['value'];
    $random = random_str(5);
    do {
        $query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ".$db_table." WHERE shortened = '".$random."';");
        if ($query != 0) {
            break;
        } else {
            $random = random_str(5);
        }
    } while (true);
    switch ($_POST['type']) {
        case "url":
            {not applicable}
        case "text":
            {not applicable}
        case "file":
            var_dump($_FILES);
            $file = $_FILES['fileToUpload'];
            $newfile = realpath(dirname(__FILE__))."/uploads/".$random.".".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,pathinfo($file['name'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
            if (!move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'],$newfile)) {
                http_response_code(500);
                echo "File error!";
                die();
            }
            mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO ".$db_table." (shortened,type,value) VALUES ('".$random."','file','".$newfile."');");
            break;
    }
    http_response_code(200);
    echo $upload_returnURL.$random;
    die();
} else { //getting a URL
    $query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM ".$db_table." WHERE shortened = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['selector'])."';");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
        $array = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
        $value = $array['value'];
        switch ($array['type']) {
            case "url":
                header("Location: ".$value);
                die();
            case "text":
                break;
            case "file":
                fpassthru(fopen($value,"rb"));
                die();
        }
    } else {
        header("Location: ".$upload_failRedirect);
        die();
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you certain the path exists? try checking first with `is_dir(pathinfo($newfile,PATHINFO_DIRNAME))` then if not, use `mkdir()` to make the directory before moving the file.

Comment: adding `if (!is_dir(pathinfo($newfile,PATHINFO_DIRNAME))) mkdir(pathinfo($newfile,PATHINFO_DIRNAME));` right before the move does nothing.

Comment: Does the folder already exist or no? Also, you would want to probably do `mkdir(pathinfo($newfile,PATHINFO_DIRNAME), 0755,true);` You need permissions and `true` so nested folders are created if not already there.

Comment: The folder already exists with permissions 0777, and that new mkdir doesn't work.